# Sending ajax request in laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

```
url = '{{route("ajaxSendmsg")}}';
            console.log(url);
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data : {comment_id:comment_id},
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success : function(response){
                    alert(response);
                },
                error : function(res){
console.log(res);
                }

            });
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/ajaxSend', ['as'=> 'ajaxSendmsg', 'uses'=>'PostsController@ajaxSend']);
```

Controller:

```
public  function ajaxSend(){

        if( Request::ajax() ){

        return Response::json(['success' => 1]);
        }

    }
```

Error: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

I'm trying to send ajax request, but it doesn't work. :/

Comment: You either have to disable the CSRF-token middleware for the route, or you send it with every request. There's a helper function `csrf_token()` which gets you the current token. The middleware will look for either a field named "_token" in the query or post string or an "X-CSRF-TOKEN" HTTP header. http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel by default has a middleware on non-reading HTTP requests (like POST, PUT or PATCH)  to protect against [Cross Site Request Forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). On every response, a token is generated, and then the subsequent request is expected to send along that token. If the tokens match, everything is fine, if not (or if the requests provides no token at all), this might be a CSRF exploit.

There are several ways to go about this:

1. Disable the middleware completely by commenting it out in `app/Http/Kernel.php` - obviously not the best idea.
2. Disable it only for the routes where you're sure you don't need it by overriding the default middleware with your own:

``

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Str::startsWith($request->getRequestUri(), 'some/open/route') {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }
}
```

3. Just send it along in every request, either in the request body as `_token`, in the request string as `_token` or as an HTTP header named `X-CSRF-TOKEN`. You can get it with the helper function `csrf_token()`:

``

```
.ajax({
   url: url,
   data : {comment_id:comment_id, "_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"},
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   ....
});
```

Comment: Can't resubmit form with same token on after validation error using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

for use ajax request and response in laravel5. you should send token like this.
::::::::

ajax file::

```
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" id="_token" name="_token" />

 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:'{{url("set-visitor")}}' ,
            data: {id: '2',  _token: $('#_token').val()},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
                var rep = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(data);
                if(rep.code == 200)
                {
                    console.log(rep);
                }
                else{
                    console.log('error');
                }
            }
        });
```

and Controller file::

```
 public function set_visitor()
{
    $id = request('id');
    $_token = request('_token');
    return Response::json($_token);

}
```

good luck:♥♥: